# Tenses when describing two subsequent past events, one of which (kind of) still goes on

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

If someone had been a teacher from 1975-2000, when he writes about it today, does he say:

> I **was/have been/had been** a teacher from when I **(can/could/could have/have)** barely remember(ed).

and a slightly different version:

> I **was/have been/had been** a teacher for more than two decades.

Answer (score 2):

*I was a teacher a teacher for more than two decades* is perfectly good to describe an event or condition from the past that does not continue to be true in the present.

> *I had been a teacher for more than two decades*

works if you want to firmly establish that your being a teacher occurred before some other past event (e.g., *I had been a teacher for two decades when I retired*).

Among your first group of options, none work, and the word *from* is problematic. You could say:

> *I was a teacher so long ago I barely remember it*

or

> *I was a teacher from that day forward.*

If it's that particular period you don't remember, you'd need to say

> *I was a teacher during a period I barely remember*

or

> *at a time I barely remember*.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually quite a lot of nuance behind how these words are used, but here are the general rules.

**Was** indicates a past state that (generally) does not persist to the present. This is the *Past Tense*.

> **I was a teacher** between 1975 and 2000. But I'm not one anymore.

If you *do not* specify a period of time, then **have been** can also be used here. This carries more of a nuance like "I have the experience of having been a teacher".

> **I have been a teacher.** But I'm not one anymore.

With a past time specified, or with other temporal words, **have been** indicates a state that has persisted from a past time to the present. This is called the *Perfect Present Continous Tense*.

> **I have been a teacher** since 1975.

**Had been** indicates a state that persisted from the past until a *later point in the past* but not necessarily until the present. It *may* persist to the present, but the author is specifically focusing on a period of time in the past during which something existed in this state. This is the *Past Perfect Tense*

> By the year 2000, **I had been a teacher** since 1975. (Or, By the year 2000, **I had been a teacher** for 25 years.)

As for **could** and **can**, **could** is the past test of **can** (among some other uses). So if the remembering is happening in the present, you use **can**, if it's happening in the past, you use **could**.

> I have been a teacher since before I **can currently** remember.
>
> I had been a teacher since before I **could at that time** remember.

Edit to answer questions asked in a comment:

> For more than two decades, IF someone had asked me to desribe myself in one word, it would have been: a teacher

The above sentence is fine with regard to tense, though I would phrase it more like this:

> For more than two decades, if someone had asked me to des**c**ribe myself in one word, **my answer** would have been **"teacher"**.

The other sentence is also fine with regard to tense:

> For more than two decades, had someone asked me to desribe myself in
> one word, it would have been: a teacher

They both mean the same thing. The second feels perhaps a bit more literary. In conversation, **if someone has asked** or even just **if someone asked** are more likely to come up.

Comment: Thanks, this was truly helpful. Could you please help me with another variation of the same situation: **"For more than two decades, IF someone had asked me to desribe myself in one word, it would have been: a teacher"** and **"For more than two decades, had someone asked me to desribe myself in one word, it would have been: a teacher"**. Are these sentences correct (especially tense-wise)? Is any of them preferrable?

Comment: I edited my answer to address your question in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the length of the other answers, most people seem to think this question is more nuanced than I do.  Be that as it may, I would simply suggest:

> I had been a teacher for as long as I could remember.

After all, if you couldn't remember something in 2000, it goes without saying that you probably still can't remember it fifteen years later.